# When going to http:/localhost@admin it shows the actual script for python

Tags: python, apache

This is my first time using an apache server and i wanted to run a test script.The file is saved under `htdocs`. Can someone advise on why its printing the code and not `"Hello World, this is a test to see if i can run this program on a server" and "Bye"`.

```
#!/Python37/python

#display Hello World
print("Hello World, this is a test to see if i can run this program on a server")
print()
print("Bye")
```

Side Note -- This is what is seen when typing in `http:/localhost@admin`

Comment: Have you started the Apache server? Sounds like the Apache web server needs to be started or restarted. You can do this either via the Apache service located in the services control panel or via the Start -> All Programs -> Apache . . . -> Control Apache Server menu option. If you're on Windows OS more information here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html

Comment: The apache server is started, i started it through services under the task manager. I am still getting the same issue. Im seeing the code when i type in http://localhost/helloWorld.py into the address bar.

Comment: I have also modified my httpd, i know my apache server is working as well

Comment: #ServerName localhost:8080

Comment: KEEP IN MIND -- IM USING WINDOWS 10